# Can I share an excel file that has a link to a text file?

Tags: excel, share

I have an Excel file that pulls data from a text file using the "Get Data From Text" option. When I try to share the document using the Review/Share Document option, the option to refresh the data from the linked text file is disabled.

Is there any way to have a linked text file that can be shared with other users in Excel?

This is on an internal network and we do not use Sharepoint.

Comment: Seems like a better fit for superusers: http://superuser.com/

Comment: If this is on the same network, why go through the Review/Share process? Avoind shared workbooks. Just save in a location where people can access the file and the linked content.

Comment: Because need to have more than one person at a time able to view/edit the document for collaboration.

Comment: That will disable some features, like externally linked data. Also, your file will become corrupt over time. If you need simultaneous multi-user edit, get a database, not Excel.

Comment: Ok good to know externally linked data will be disabled when sharing. For my purposes I need to stick with excel due to the resources and time to do the project.

Comment: @jroyce the other option might be to use google sheets for this, it is very good at exactly this task (only downside is if you are at work and prohibited from using google).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'm trying a workaround by having my shared file open a hyperlink to the linked excel sheet that can be read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this having two excel workbooks, the first containing any shared, editable data with a hyperlink to the second file which is a read only workbook that gets its data from the text file.

Any data the user needs can be moved to the first workbook with VBA code embedded behind a hyperlink to copy and paste the data into the first sheet.